# Retrieve the date of the first representation of a resource in DBpedia

Tags: dbpedia

I wanna know if there is a way to find out the date of the first representation of a resource in DBpedia (for this resource as an example: http://dbpedia.org/page/Mario_Balotelli)?

Comment: Also asked (and answered) on [the DBpedia Forum](https://forum.dbpedia.org/t/retreive-the-date-of-the-first-representation-of-a-ressource-in-dbpedia/158)...

Comment: Note that the page [`<http://dbpedia.org/page/Mario_Balotelli>`](http://dbpedia.org/page/Mario_Balotelli) delivers the description (a/k/a representation) of the resource [`<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mario_Balotelli>`](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mario_Balotelli).